# wp rest api v2 return json_no_route

Tags: wp-api, rest-api

i am using WP rest API v1 and everything is ok.

But now i want taste some WP rest API v2. 
the problem is, when i cal:

> mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

or:

> mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/post

or

> mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/

or any thing else is related ti this path:

> mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2...

the result is:

```
[{"code":"json_no_route","message":"\u0647\u06cc\u0686 \u0645\u0633\u06cc\u0631 \u062a\u0637\u0628\u06cc\u0642 URL \u0648 \u0631\u0648\u0634 \u062f\u0631\u062e\u0648\u0627\u0633\u062a \u067e\u06cc\u062f\u0627 \u0634\u062f"}]
```

and i don't know what is the problem and the point is i want to use WP rest API v1 and v2, together, so disabling WP rest API v1 is not an option.

PS: I removed and add WP rest API v2 but nothing change.

Comment: Sorry to say but you have two options for the moment. Asking at the correct forum when issues arise with this [specific (*3rd party*)plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/rest-api) or at [github](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) or you wait till the update from WP to version 4.5 (*which will be in early April 2016*). Note: if I am incorrect, and you are not using that plugin, I will delete my comment!

Comment: oh thanks dear dear @Charles, i post my issue there. it was so nice of you to guide me .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, i find my answer.
Just ask it [here](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2343#issuecomment-192487381) and as dear Charles sayed, they answered me, so fast, the answer is:

> By default, WP-API v1 takes priority over v2. If v1 is installed and
>   activated, then v2 routes are inaccessible.
>
> To mitigate this, you'll need to register either v1 or v2 to a
>   different base than wp-json. Both have filters to make this more or
>   less easily possible:

```
add_filter( 'rest_url_prefix', function() {
    return 'wp-api';
});
```

and because i am not a WordPress guy, so i don't know where should i add this lines so i get help from [this blog](http://buddydev.com/wp-tips/modifying-api-base-url-prefix-for-wp-rest-api-plugin/) and add the lines to the

> function.php

of my them.

Comment: +1 That is great to hear, you got your answer/solution and posted it here so others also know how to solve that issue. Please don't forget to mark your answer as solved. (*I believe for 'new' ppl it takes two days before able to do*)